# For a Quarto website, how to hide "On this page" bar/stack?

Tags: quarto

I've checked the Quarto guide but it only describes how to hide the navbar and sidebar, which is not the "On this page" bar seen below on the right (in the margin):

[image: Quarto Guide]

Comment: Can you share your `_quarto.yml` file. Probably its due to the `toc: true` in the yaml file.

Comment: That was it! Or even just removing headers that start with #. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the `_quarto.yml` file from `toc: true` to `toc: false`.